# Survey component that can be embeded locally

Tags: php, survey

I'm working with PHP and need to add a survey component. I would prefer something that allows me to embed the survey on the site. The creation of the survey itself can be off-site, no problem there, as long as the users themselves don't have to go elsewhere to answer the survey. Does something like this already exist?

There's another issue: some of the surveys may be closed surveys i.e. sent to a specific group of emails and only those can answer it. So I'm guessing the user will have to click a link which has his email and code coded as parameters. Any other ways to do the same thing that I may be missing?

I'm open to all suggestions... but would really prefer not to have to install an entire open source system for this, unless all else fails.

Comment: Could always just use an iframe to embed a 3rd party survey...

Answer (score 1):

[Wufoo](http://wufoo.com/) and [SurveyMonkey](http://www.surveymonkey.com/) are both really good for this, especially given your requirements. I'd advise you rethink using PHP, per se, and consider embedding one of these in your site (you can control the HTML/CSS so it looks the same). Otherwise, there are quite a few options for you to evaluate... [see](http://answers.google.com/answers/threadview?id=311751) [these](http://php.resourceindex.com/Complete_Scripts/Survey_and_Voting/) [lists](http://www.hotscripts.com/category/php/scripts-programs/polls-voting/).

Answer (score 0):

There exist many survey extensions. Maybe you'd like to use survey extension by Joomplace. Now I'm developing an e-commerce website so I think to buy this one. Here is their site: http://www.joomplace.com.  I know that this survey supports front-end authoring and it's also possible to create different kinds of reports. Also you can define the list of users you want to address the survey to. But this is for Joomla based sites.